# Oracle - Bad performance when using Left Join ON Where IS NULL

Tags: oracle, left-join, isnull

As my title. I have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT "Student_ID", "ID_Card", "First_Name", "Last_Name" FROM "STUDENT@DBLA
 WHERE "YEAR" = 2018 AND "SEX" = 'FEMALE') T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Student_ID, ID_Card, First_Name, Last_Name FROM schema.STUDENTS
           WHERE YEAR = 2018 AND SEX = 'FEMALE') D
ON D.ID_Card = T."ID_Card" WHERE D.ID IS NULL;
```

This query run very low, maybe stop when I add Where is null clause behind. 
Any solution for this issue? 
Many Thanks!

Comment: Hi. And you learned what googing re slow queries & so tried what? Please read & act on  [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also [mcve] re code queries.

Comment: Without the `EXPLAIN PLAN` it is hard to tell. It could also be network latency 
across DB link.You may rewrite the query using `NOT EXISTS` but can't be sure If it helps.One important point though, your `LEFT JOIN` is  ON `D.ID_Card = T."ID_Card"` and you are checking `WHERE D.ID IS NULL` .So, if ID is nullable column the condition could become true. Better check it on the joined column id_card, and that should ideally have a `UNIQUE key/ index or be a PRIMARY key`

Comment: @KaushikNayak That's not about network, because the statement run fast without Where clause. I'm checked constraint and condition ID IS NOT NULL, so It's true

Comment: Could you post your explain plan please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try writing your query as a direct left join, without resorting to subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t1.Student_ID,
    t1.ID_Card,
    t1.First_Name,
    t1.Last_Name,
    t2.Student_ID AS Student_ID_2
    t2.ID_Card AS ID_Card_2,
    t2.First_Name AS First_Name_2,
    t2.Last_Name AS Last_Name_2
FROM "STUDENT@DBLA" t1
LEFT JOIN schema.STUDENTS t2
    ON t1.ID_Card = t2.IDCard AND
       t2.YEAR = 2018 AND t2.SEX = 'FEMALE' AND t2.ID IS NULL
WHERE
    t1.YEAR = 2018 AND t1.SEX = 'FEMALE';
```

The reason why you might want to avoid using subqueries here is that it can force Oracle to materialize an intermediate result in your total query.  This can be costly from a performance point of view, for many reasons.

Comment: Thank you, It worked.
I have another question, as I know, hint not work in DML query use DBLink. Any solution improve the performance in that case?